# Kotlin app using Admob and Firebase, but the app doesn't run, saying that there is a problem with the Firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, kotlin, admob

I made an app using Firebase and Admob, and the Kotlin app, which worked fine, doesn't work after wipe data from the emulator. The error code is as follows.

**"The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date"**

I've tried resetting firebase, but it still won't launch. What's wrong?

The build gradle and manifest are attached below.

**build gradle(project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build gradle(module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jym.qb"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'

}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jym.qb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Qb"
        android:name=".SharedValue"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".ManageQuestionActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".KeywardActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GetQuestionActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkbookActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PartActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExamActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After taking a walk to cool off for an hour, the app works normally.    Looking at the Google Admob documentation, I found the following:

"Key Point: New test devices typically start serving test ads in your app within 15 minutes, but it can also take up to 24 hours."

While initializing the data of the virtual emulator, it seems that Admob recognizes it as a new mobile phone and delays the time. Could it be that what I was thinking was correct?